# blackscreen in blackmagic media express

Tags: debian, hdmi

I'm trying to check if my blackmagic intensity pro 4k  capture card works correctly.I installed drivers -version 10.8.6 for debian,linux.I connected stb via hdmi to capture but as in the picture ,I see blackscreen in Media Express Tool.I tried to change input output formats but didn't work.Which   formats should I choose  to take capture? or any solution for this? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about that hdmi input and output values.try to find correct values according to your sysytem :)